# how to add java web application to main server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I m new to java web programming . Currently I am developing a java web application using tomcat in my pc. Can anyone suggest how to add this application to main network , such that other users can also use this application.

Softwares used - tomcat ,netbeans and mysql

Thanks .

Comment: Main network means on www or in your network (Intranet) ?

Comment: I meant the network in organization - Intranet .

Comment: Okay Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make `.war` file of your project, check that all configuration okay or not.

`Stop Tomcat Service` by going in bin directory of tomcat.

Make war then `tomcat directory -> webapp` then paste that war file to it and start the service.

Now Check that your firewall allows port `8080 Inboubnd rules` or not.

In firewall advance setting In inbound rules create new rule then select port then add `8080` in this next next ok.

Now from any other PC check by typing your PC 's IP like `192.168.1.10:8080/appname`.

If got problem post me.

Comment: Another important point - bind tomcat listener to `*` to listen on all network interfaces or the IP address of a specific network interface if you prefer. No one else can connect to your tomcat instance if your tomcat listens on `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @sa1991 - Have you solved your problem ? Is your App Accessible from other PC ?