# Run jsp pages from remote server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP and servlets. I configured my eclipse and am now able to run a helloworld jsp program. Now, i want this to be run on a different system.

Following were my queries.

1) Can i enter the IP of my current system where eclipse and tomcat are installed and running and run the application on the computer 2?

2) If question one is not possible, how can i test my application outside local host without purchasing the server.

Please share your knowledge

Comment: you can upload ur app on herokuapp..

Comment: @Anirban, yes i am lan connected, so if i just give http://my_computer1_ip/index.jsp instead of http://localhost:8080/index.jsp, it should behave the same r8?

Comment: You want to use your app in your intranet or www ?

Comment: @user3145373, Its an intranet based application mate!! (For a college library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, option number 1 should work.

You currently have a webapplication running on your local machine. So you can enter something like `http://localhost:8080/myapp` in your browser and see a webpage from your application.

Next step to replace localhost with an ip adress or computer name. So still on the same computer the following should work: `http://192.168.123.1:8080/myapp` and `http://mycomputer:8080/myapp`. Of course I just made the ip address and the computer name up and you have the real values.

These two urls should also work from a remote computer that is on the same network. Like the computer of you coworker, or the second computer in your home network.

Possibly the next step would be to deploy your application on a cloud service. But that is a different story worth its own question.

Comment: Thanks mate, that cleared most of my queries!! So, for an intranet based application which i am looking for, having 2 computers with LAN connection should work!!

Answer (score 0):

You can put your app in `tomcat directory/webapp`.
you have to put there .war file of your application.

Then from firewall add `inbound rules` that on `port 8080` incoming request to all connection.

then from at any place from your intranet just type `your ip :8080/app`.

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175714/how-to-add-java-web-application-to-main-server/24175783#24175783) my answer of same query like you.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible in LAN you just need to put the SERVER IP instead of localhost
example: 192.168.1.23:8080/test

if you want to  access it in outside via Internet connection
first you should have STATIC IP it is provided by your internet service provider ask them.

and dont forget to off your firewall or add it to exception